# Trouble with trailing stop loss based on candle low + some ticks

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am creating a basic strategy and am facing some issues with stop loss execution.

```
strategy("Same lows",overlay=false,pyramiding=9999,calc_on_every_tick=true)

if low[0]-low[1]==0 and year>2020
    strategy.entry("buy",strategy.long,2)
    
x = low[1]-0.04
if x<low[0]-0.04
    x:=low[0]-0.04


strategy.exit("tsl","buy",stop=x,trail_points=0,trail_offset=low[1]-4)
```

This is the complete code. Also I intend to add variables once this issue is fixed.
Any help is welcome.
Thank you

Comment: "trail_offset (float) An optional parameter. Trailing stop price (specified in ticks)" - from the Pine reference. This is the offset from maximum price (defined by trail_points) reached from the entry price.

Comment: Yes, so to trail the price from the beginning, I used trail_points=0, and specified trail_offset as low - 4 ticks of the previous candle. Some trades are executed perfectly on this basis, but still I am seeing some discrepancies wherein the profit is booked at a random price or stop loss being triggered late.

Comment: Also I am unable to find any source which guides in putting a tick based stop loss.

Comment: If you want to specify 4 ticks for trail_offset that `trail_offset=low[1]-4` is wrong value. The correct is `trail_offset=4`